# What is the section in a business card that shows home contact details called?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

On my business card I have the contact details of my office, however I want to include the contact details of my home.

I want to make it known that the above details are my home's. How can I write it? "Residence contact details"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same pattern people use to differentiate business vs. personal phone numbers, now that cell phones are ubiquitous, and abbreviate, with O for Office and H for Home.

Villofkia

**O:** 111 Business Street

**H:** 222 Residential Street

Comment: Or spell out "Business" / "Office" & "Home". Depending which country you're in, abbreviations may not always be obvious. Also, bear in mind that in the UK, "my cell" sounds as if you are in prison - we call them "mobile phones" and not everyone is familiar with the US term.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities.  Here are two that might be common:

- Home vs Office
- Residence vs Business

Answer (score 0):

On a business card, space is at a premium. So -- bearing in mind that single-letter abbreviations are problematic, for the reason TrevorD gives in his comment -- I'd keep the descriptors to a minimum, as follows:

> Home:
>
> Address line 1
>
> Address line 2 (etc.)
>
> Phone

Similarly:

> Business (*or* Office):
>
> Address line 1
>
> Address line 2 (etc.)
>
> Phone